# XAMPP - Port 80 in use by... though I cahnged the port to 8080

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf, ports

I've changed the ports as posted on other threads
httpd-ssl.conf: `Listen 8080`, `ServerName localhost:8080`

Edited the httpd-ssl.conf as well: 
`Listen 4433`, `<VirtualHost _default_:4433>` `,ServerName www.example.com:4433`

I don't get it because Apache starting, but only after these error messages...
Just wondering if it's fine to leave it like this, and what could cause the problem.

```
[Apache] Problem detected!
[Apache] Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
[Apache] Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
[Apache] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
[Apache] or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
[Apache] Attempting to start Apache app...
[Apache] Status change detected: running
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egogn.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what caused the problem.. It was the IIS.
To fix it - open "run" (Winkey + R) write services.msc, then search for `World Wide Web Publishing Service` and set it to Manual. If you don't need it, you can go to `Control Panel>Programs and Features>Turn Windows features on or off`, and uncheck "Internet Information Services" click OK, restart is required.
I believe that for some people it'll be enough to edit the XAMPP `httpd.conf`, and set the port to 8080 or whatever is available.

UPDATE: It seems it wasn't the IIS! You don't even need to change the IIS to Manual startUp. In addition to the `httpd.conf` we need to configure the main ports. Open XAMPP click on config (The one with the wrench icon) >Service and Port Settings> Change the "main Port" and "SSL Port" for e.g 8080, 4433 Click `Save` and there you go :)
XAMPP v.3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can check which ports are in use by opening cmd and typeing

```
netstat -all
```

But most likely port 8080 is in use.

Just change the port to something else, you don't have to change any other settings.

Comment: Hi, tried netstat -n, there's no port8080 in use...
And I also changed to different ports for example 7777 or 8081

Comment: When you restart appache, does it say Port 8080(or whatever port you used) in use?

Comment: It says "Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!"
But under Port(s) 4433,8080

Comment: You did not edit the right config file, if you changed to use port 8080 then if it does not work, it would say Port 8080 in use.

Comment: Check the screenshot... I did edit the right file, otherwise it wouldn't show these ports